# twocolumn with minipage over full width

Tags: two-column, minipage, columns

I'm trying to make something similar to http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00734b.pdf
I'm using the twocolumn option, and have defined my own \showtitle command:

```
\newcommand{\showtitle}{
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
  \flushright\textbf{\fontsize{50}{1}\selectfont\gettitle{}}
  \vbox {\vskip3mm\hrule width \hsize height 1.5pt\vskip1mm\hrule width \hsize height 4pt\vskip1mm} 
  \flushleft\textbf{\Huge{\getsubtitle}}
  \vbox {\vskip2mm\hrule width \hsize height 4pt\vskip1mm\hrule width \hsize height     1.5pt\vskip1mm} 
  \normalsize\normalfont}
}
```

The formatting is OK, however, the second column starts at the top of the column, behind the title...
I tried it with minipage as well, not working.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% General information
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\gettitle}{CBus}
\newcommand{\getsubtitle}{Protocol Specification}
\newcommand{\getauthor}{Keelan}
\newcommand{\getdate}{\today}

\title{\gettitle}
\subtitle{\getsubtitle}
\author{\getauthor}
\date{\getdate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% General layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\columnsep}{6mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Special functions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\showtitle}{
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
  \flushright\textbf{\fontsize{50}{1}\selectfont\gettitle{}}
  \vbox {\vskip3mm\hrule width \hsize height 1.5pt\vskip1mm\hrule width \hsize height     4pt\vskip1mm} 
  \flushleft\textbf{\Huge{\getsubtitle}}
  \vbox {\vskip2mm\hrule width \hsize height 4pt\vskip1mm\hrule width \hsize height     1.5pt\vskip1mm} 
  \normalsize\normalfont}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\showtitle{}

\section{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You might want to add a `%` after every `{` which ends a line to avoid a spurious space there. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/2975) for the details.

Comment: Done that. It actually worked because of the spurious space in `\flushright\textbf{\fontsize{50}{1}\selectfont\gettitle{}}`. Now using `\flushright\textbf{\fontsize{50}{1}\selectfont\gettitle{}} %`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `\twocolumn` command is your friend

```
...
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\showtitle]
...
```